# Calling function in Yii controller with renderPartial

Tags: php, yii, renderpartial

Code from controller:

```
public function actionSomeName($param){
    do something here...

    $this->renderPartial('_formCalculations', array(
        'modelX'=>$modelX,
        'modelY'=>$modelY,
    )); 

}
```

I want to call that function in my view, but it won't work.
Is `$this->renderPartial` correct ? I think not, because it's only for views? But which function do I have to use then?

```
$this->renderPartial('Controllername/Somename',array("param"=>"value"));
```

Comment: why not you call that function in controller and send it output to view while render?

Comment: Because I call this function in another view

Answer (score 0):

You can't call the controller/action directly in the view.

You can user render/renderPartial. **Render/renderPartial reference
a view file, not a controller action**

You could put in your logic in the code as well (in your example, the "do something here..." part) but that is not good MVC!

The other alternative is to use a [widget](http://yiitutorials.net/easy/creating-a-widget-with-the-yii-framework)

Answer (score 0):

Surly you can`t use renserPartial individually, but you can do it so:

```
$body = $this->renderPartial('Controllername/Somename',array("param"=>"value"),true);
```

In this code you have that view file`s scripts and you can use them anywhere you need.